# Is there a way to make a ggplot graph by taking timeseries from one DF and data from other?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a timeseries object which contains datetime and corresponding to those I have data which are contained in a separate DF. Is there a way to plot the timeseries of this data using ggplot without having to merge these two dataframes?

I could not find a way yet how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In general you can use multiple datasets with ggplot2. However, in ggplot2 each layer has only one data, i.e. you can draw a line using data from one dataset and another line using data from the second dataset. But you can't draw a line using data from both datasets. For more help please provide provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a working code example and a snippet of your data(sets) or some fake data.